# pandas apply groupby on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data, with 2 indices (date and time) which I imported with pandas.read_csv() and it looks initially like this:

```
Date         Time                   Volume
2016-01-04   2018-04-25 09:01:29    53645
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    1345
             ....
2016-01-05   2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
             2018-04-25 12:01:29    213
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
             ....
```

I want to group it for every day on groups of 20min bins. It should look like this.

```
Date         Time                   Volume
2016-01-04   2018-04-25 09:00:00    53645
             2018-04-25 09:20:00    456453
             2018-04-25 09:40:00    13153
             ....
             2018-04-25 17:00:00    13153
2016-01-05   2018-04-25 09:00:00    46465
             2018-04-25 09:20:00    454688
             2018-04-25 09:40:00    45645
             ....
             2018-04-25 17:00:00    45646
```

I've already achieved what I want, but I'm quite sure, that there is a more "pythonic" and less memory consuming way to achieve my goal.
My code now looks like:

```
    frames = []
    for date, sub_df in _file_data.groupby(level=0):
        gr = sub_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=1, freq="20min")).sum()
        frames.append(gr)
    _file_data = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('Date').resample('20min').sum()
print (df1)
                                Volume
Date       Time                       
2016-01-04 2018-04-25 09:00:00   53645
           2018-04-25 09:20:00       0
           2018-04-25 09:40:00       0
           2018-04-25 10:00:00    1468
2016-01-05 2018-04-25 10:00:00     246
           2018-04-25 10:20:00       0
           2018-04-25 10:40:00       0
           2018-04-25 11:00:00       0
           2018-04-25 11:20:00       0
           2018-04-25 11:40:00       0
           2018-04-25 12:00:00     213
```

Comment: Do you know how I can transform the second index to show only the time instead of date and time?

Comment: @Krasnars - You can use `df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1).time, level=1)`